# low speed and take more to display

Tags: mysql, join, query-performance

When I fire the below the mysql query it takes the query [Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 13,436 total, Query took 0.1715 sec)] time in chrom but its takes more time to displaying about 3 to 5 min. I have total delivery_to_shop a  13,418 rows and table shopdelivery_to_client b 7000 rows and others fewers rows. I'm trying to optimise but not success,
I'm trying to findout what is the prob? the query as below:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT(a.`factory_deli_id`),a.`shop_id`,a.`entry_date`,(a.slip_no) AS FSNo,(s.shop_name) AS FShopName,(i.dress_type_entry) AS FInitItem,(a.item_qty) AS FQty,FORMAT(i.price_rate_max, 2) AS FItemRate,FORMAT(a.item_qty*i.price_rate_max, 2) AS FTot,
b.`entry_date`,b.`shop_id`, b.`factory_item_id`, b.`slip_no`
FROM delivery_to_shop a 
INNER JOIN init_item_entry i 
ON a.factory_item_id = i.factory_item_id
INNER JOIN shop_name_entry s 
ON a.shop_id = s.shop_id
LEFT JOIN shopdelivery_to_client b
ON a.`slip_no` = b.`slip_no`
AND a.`factory_item_id` = b.`factory_item_id` 
AND a.`shop_id` = b.`shop_id`
```

Any Help?

Comment: Did you try ```EXPLAIN SELECT yourquery...```?

Comment: Thx to replay. How I DESCRIBE/EXPLAIN Multiple table? I mean type of process?

Comment: YES. I Explain table But Display Max row i,e tb a 13,860 where row exist 13,418 and tb b 8,204 where row exist 7,780 ?? !! where IS my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Add some indices for a start:

```
ALTER TABLE delivery_to_shop ADD INDEX index1 (factory_item_id, shop_id, slip_no)
ALTER TABLE init_item_entry ADD INDEX index2 (init_item_entry)
ALTER TABLE shop_name_entry ADD INDEX index3 (shop_id)
ALTER TABLE shopdelivery_to_client ADD INDEX index4 (factory_item_id, shop_id, slip_no)
```